# When I run a C# parameterized query, it times out. Same query with hard-coded parameters works fine

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get all IDs where the Text column contains the string filter.

When I run this parameterized query, it times out:

```
SqlCommand cmd =
new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE Text LIKE @filter", conn);
 if (filter != null)
 {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", "%" + filter + "%");
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Locks up here!
 }
```

When I run the same code, but with hard-coded search parameters, it returns in a timely manner with the results I wanted:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = 
 new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE Text LIKE '%patternToMatch%'", conn);
 SqlDataReader reader;
 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

In what ways do the two queries differ? I think the parameterization is doing something more than a simple text replacement.

CLARIFICATION: I'm talking to a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 server.

NEW INFORMATION: It only times out when the search filter is longer than 6 characters.

EDIT: SOLVED! I set the search up as a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TextSearch 
@filter varchar(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableName WHERE [Text] LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
END
GO
```

Comment: What does `filter` contain?

Comment: It's a string primitive.

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler and make sure that when executed both queries are the same ?

Comment: try to add this at the end of the `Like statement` `LIKE ?` like this
`SqlCommand cmd =
new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE Text LIKE ?", conn);`

Comment: DJ KRAZE: I forgot to mention that this is a SQL Server 2012 project. I think I have to use named parameters.

Comment: If I had to guess: parameter sniffing. Search for "optimize for unknown"

Comment: try "SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE Text LIKE '@filter'" ( wrap  filter parameter with ')
also posible your filter is empty string and get VERY heavy query with %%

Comment: Try not adding the % when inserting the value into the parameter.

Comment: @gabba: I tried wrapping it in the single quotes. There was some progress; it now returns no hits very quickly. I've checked that the search term should have hits, and that filter is not an empty string.

Comment: you don't need to wrap the parameter in single quotes - ado.net submits it as a paramatised sp_executesql statement.  Im reasonably sure there is no difference in the query plan between both statements

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler to see what query is coming across the wire to the server?  That would be my first step.

Comment: I have had the same issue with parameterized queries and can't figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED! I set the search up as a stored procedure:

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TextSearch 
@filter varchar(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableName WHERE [Text] LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
END
GO
```

C#:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TextSearch", conn);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filter", filter));
```

Now it executes as quickly as I'd expect for queries of all lengths.

Answer (score 0):

When using paramaterized queries with the like operator, you need to single quote the wildcard character:

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE Text LIKE '%' + @filter + '%' ", conn);
```

Then just add the parameter as usual:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filter);
```