# Timeout when using parameterized queries with no results returned.. ONLY in those circumstances

Tags: .net, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2, timeout

We're attempting to troubleshoot some DB server timeouts, and I was able to reduce it to the following:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("*connectionstring*");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
var sql = "select top 10 a.id from idx a inner join docs b on a.id=b.id " +
    "where b.status in ('X','Y','Z') and a.sc=@SC and a.name like @Name " +
    "order by a.id";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SC","NC");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name","%ZZZ%");
DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (r.Read()) {
  }
}
DateTime after = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + before.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("After:  " + after.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(after - before);
con.Close();
```

The above times out at the ExecuteReader statement.

If I change the parameter value "%ZZZ%" to "%SMITH%", it comes back almost instantly.  Even better, if I remove the command parameters and change the CommandText syntax to pure sql, ie-"... where sc='NC' and name like '%ZZZ%'", it **also** comes back almost instantly.

Any thoughts?  I'm at a loss, and can't find any other threads where people have had similar issues.  Thanks in advance!

**Update #1: We were able to replicate the same functionality with a small Java console app, so it does not appear to be a .Net or driver issue.

**Update #2: This is a very similar problem to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881161/when-i-run-a-c-sharp-parameterized-query-it-times-out-same-query-with-hard-cod).  Not exactly the same cause, but identical effect.

Comment: Did you happen to figure out what was going on? I'm looking at something that appears to be the same issue, and I'm not seeing a lot in the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you try to profile server queries using Sql Server Profiler. You might get some clues there.

Comment: Good thought.  I captured a trace of both the bad and good executions.  They're identical in the trace, with the exception of the values being passed.  It must be a SQL Server issue, though, because we were able to duplicate this problem in a small Java project as well.